# Infinispan : change dynamically jgroups multicast port

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

We recently deployed an app using infinispan (first time)
This app runs in 3 environments (test (2 nodes), pilote (2 nodes) and production (4 nodes)).

My issue is that each node sees the 7 others. It's normal because the jgroups UDP config file is the same for everyone so they all talk using the same port.

I would like to set by code a specific port for each environment to avoid maintaining a specific config

Our config file is stored in our custom [stack](https://github.com/openwide-java/owsi-core-parent), (shared with all of our projects and I don't want the stack to depend on the projects environments definition)

I found the "Protocol" class but I have difficulties to get the link with the infinispan manager

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable for the mcast port, e.g. `<UDP mcast_port="${my.mcast.port:15000}"`. Setting system property `my.mcast.port` would override the default of `15000`.

You can get the `UDP` protocol and change the port programmatically in JGroups, but in Infinispan, this doesn't make any sense as - by the time the cache has been created - JGroups has already been started and the port cannot be changed after the JChannel has been connected.

Comment: Thx, We endly chose this solution : the point was to define the right location to load the variable early enough.